# Why doesn't javascript respond to this?

Tags: javascript

```
// Any JS code here works
    whatever({
    });
// Any JS code here doesn't work
```

Just wondering because i see the "whatever" affects on the code that belows it when it's closed already

Comment: Did you look at the javascript console? What did it tell you?

Comment: To me, There is an error in wathever that halt the script execution. With the little information you give us, it is the only guess that have sense to me.

Comment: `whatever()` is probably throwing an exception. It is pretty much essential to code JavaScript with your browser's console open. Firebug is recommended for Firefox, or use the Developer Tools in Chrome/Safari, or F12 for Dev Tools in IE 8+

Comment: There is *nothing* here that would be useful in determining what the problem is. If you really want your problem solved, you need to provide the necessary information.

Answer (score 2):

```
whatever({
});
```

is a function call.  Any (uncaught) errors that occur in this function—or if this function is not defined in this scope—will cause your script execution to halt.  That's likely why the code beneath it is not running.

You Firebug / Chrome Dev console can help you identify the error that's happening.

---

**EDIT**

The best way to fix this is to fix your script so that it doesn't throw an error.  But, if you just need a simple way to ignore any errors, you could surround the call to `whatever` in a try catch block

```
        try {
            whatever({});
        } catch (error) { }

        alert("Need this to run");

        function whatever(obj) {
            obj.er.rr.ed = 3;
        }
```

But again, you should really fix the error that's occurring.

Comment: is it being called normally like this : whatever() ?

Comment: @user1150271 - I'm not sure what you mean.  Just check your dev console to see what errors are being thrown

Comment: What if whatever was w.whatever, i guess this is not meant by function because functions can't contain dots, can it ?

Comment: If you have an object called `w`, which has a **method** called `whatever`, then you would absolutely call it with `w.whatever()`

Comment: Is there a way to force to continue processing rest of page?